# C# I have an array of superclass objects, which may contain subclass objects. How to test for subclass object & use it's accessors?

Tags: c#

I have an `Array` of `AutoMobiles`
This array may contain SubClass Objects `Truck` or `Car`.

How do I test a Position in the Array for the type of Object?
eg:

```
if(AutoMobileArray[1].IsObject(Car)){}
```

The `Car` Class has a unique Accessor

```
public String BootSpace()
```

How can I use the SubClass Objects Accessors?
eg:

```
if(AutoMobileArray[1].IsObject(Car))
{
    BootSpaceLabel.Text = AutoMobileArray[1].BootSpace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, If I understand you correctly, there's the `is` operator:

```
if(AutoMobileArray[1] is Car)
{
  //Do stuff here
}
```

To do stuff with the subclass (access methods defined in the subclass etc.) you need to cast:

```
if(AutoMobileArray[1] is Car)
{
  Car c = (Car)AutoMobileArray[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(AutoMobileArray[1] is Car){ }
```

`is` operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.71).aspx

You can then cast to the appropriate type:

```
if(AutoMobileArray[1] is Car)
{
    Car car = (Car)AutoMobileArray[1];
    BootSpaceLabel.Text = car.BootSpace();
}
```

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thanks! 
Do you know how to use the accessors of the Subclass?
The code I have above won't work.

Comment: Either my answer or the answer give by @hunter work though they use different methods to perform the cast.

Comment: Yes, cast to the the Type you want to use it as. I've edited the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
Car car = AutoMobileArray[1] as Car;
if(car != null)
{
    BootSpaceLabel.Text = car.BootSpace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks my feathered friend :D

Comment: For the record, although this pattern is suggested by FxCop using as doesn't perform user defined conversions so in the unlikely case those will be added at some point, you might just want to stick to `is`

Comment: @MichaelDmitryAzarkevich: `is` doesn't perform  user defined conversions as well.

Comment: @dtb But an explicit cast operation does.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use such expression:

```
if (AutoMobileArray[1] is Car)
{
    BootSpaceLabel.Text = AutoMobileArray[1].BootSpace();
}
```

Although there are some workarounds how not to use the "is" keyword, e.g. you can define method in `AutoMobile` class like this:

```
virtual string BootSpace()
{ 
    return string.Empty; 
}
```

or

```
abstract string BootSpace();
```

and `override` this method in Car subclass (and other subclasses, according to yout business logic):

```
override string BootSpace()
{
    //Car bootspace logic here 
}
```

After that you can simply call `BootSpaceLabel.Text = AutoMobileArray[1].BootSpace();` without checking object type;

More advanced and "beautiful" way to handle this problem is to use "Design Patterns". There are many standard design problems that are solved effectively. They are known as Design Patterns. In your case the Strategy Pattern might be useful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern